# Probable reasons for Illegal seek in socket programming

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I have received following error while sending data.

send:29-Illegal seek

Please explain the probable reasons for it. I am new to socket programming. Thanks in advance.

```
CHAR datasend[200];
    DOUBLE64 fTime=0.0;
    LONG32 sent_bytes=0;
    while(TRUE)
    {
            memset(datasend,0,200);
            fTime=getTime();
            sprintf(datasend,"0=%.0lf ",fTime);
            sent_bytes = send ( isockfd, datasend, strlen(datasend),0);
            logDebug1("Pulse is %s and data bytes is %d",datasend,strlen(datasend));
            if(sent_bytes <= 0)
            {
                    logPError("send");
                    logTimestamp("Closing socket\n");
                    close(isockfd);
                    return NULL;
            }

            sleep(25);

    }
```

Comment: You forgot to post the relevant source code.

Comment: There you go. I have edited and added the source code

Comment: @user1095108 : Could u please elaborate

Comment: remove `logDebug1`, and check again

Comment: @user2531564 Never mind, you're interpreting errno wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

**You're not interpreting the right error** because of the intervening `logDebug1` call.

- You have a `send` that returns something <= 0 and possibly an `errno` that you could inspect
- You print something (`logDebug1`) **which likely clobbers `errno`**
- You do some sort of `perror` which interprets the clobbered `errno`

What you want to do instead is check if `sentBytes < 0`, **`perror` immediately** and then maybe print more debugging stuff if you want.

Comment: logDebug1 and logPError and logTimestamp are the functions that print data using printf and perror functions.. My query on broader picture is that, what are the possible reasons to get Illegal seek error .

Comment: @user2531564: if you don't reflect on what he wrote, how should we know whether you understood a word of it?

Comment: @user2531564 The 'broader picture' is that you *didn't* get an 'illegal seek' error from a socket operation. You got a *presently unknown* error, which you corrupted by doing other things between getting it and printing it. Do pay attention.